# Setting the Data Source for a Report

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to make a button in an Access form which will run a couple queries and then take the resultant recordsets and put them into reports. I have gotten to the point where the button will call the module, it creates the proper recordsets, and then it creates the reports. However, the reports are blank, they don't have the data in them from the recordsets. I think my problem is that I haven't properly assigned the data source of the reports but I can't figure out how to if that is the issue.

```
Private Function showReport(sectionHeading As String, SQL As String, recordset As ADODB.Recordset)
Dim textBox As Access.textBox ' textbox control
Dim label As Access.label ' label control
Dim report As report ' hold report object
Dim controlTop As Long ' holds top value of control position
Dim controlLeft As Long ' holds left value of control position
Dim title As String 'holds title of report
Dim i As Integer 'iterator
i = 0

title = sectionHeading

controlLeft = 0
controlTop = 0

Set report = CreateReport

report.Width = 8500
report.Caption = title

Set label = CreateReportControl(report.Name, acLabel, _
acPageHeader, , "Title", 0, 0)
label.FontBold = True
label.FontSize = 12
label.SizeToFit

For Each fld In recordset.fields
    Set textBox = CreateReportControl(report.Name, acTextBox, _
    acDetail, , fld.Name, controlLeft + 1500, controlTop)
    textBox.SizeToFit

    Set label = CreateReportControl(report.Name, acLabel, acDetail, _
    textBox.Name, fld.Name, controlLeft, controlTop, 1400, textBox.Height)
    label.SizeToFit

    controlTop = controlTop + textBox.Height + 25

    i = i + 1
Next

Set label = CreateReportControl(report.Name, acLabel, _
acPageFooter, , Now(), 0, 0)

Set textBox = CreateReportControl(report.Name, acTextBox, _
acPageFooter, , "='Page ' & [Page] & ' of ' & [Pages]", report.Width - 1000, 0)
textBox.SizeToFit

report.RecordSource = SQL

DoCmd.OpenReport report.Name, acViewPreview

recordset.Close
Set recordset = Nothing
Set report = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: What have you set your datasource to? You don't show that here - is it a query or table - what's the SQL if it's query? If you open the report by itself - are there any pages with data? What is "CreateReport" and "CreateReportControl"?

Comment: What version of MS-Access are you using - please update your tags

Comment: Well the problem is that I haven't found any way to set the data source from a module external to the report. The intent is to have the data source be a query. When I run it, the report opens with the proper formatting but without any of the data, just #Name? in every field.

Comment: That's not the problem - the problem is that you aren;t showing your code - or if that is all you have for now then it certainly won't compile. When you can get your code to compile, then copy/paste your code for CreateReport and CreateReportControl - those are not built-in Access functions.

Comment: @dbmitch: They are: [Application.CreateReport](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193499.aspx) and [Application.CreateReportControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193518.aspx). Usually one builds wizards with these methods. [Example](http://www.icodeguru.com/database/programming.microsoft.office.access.2003/8368final/LiB0042.html)

Comment: That's available in Office 2013 - not 2010. Is that what you're using @Ulthran

Comment: I'm using 2010 but I haven't seen any errors regarding the use of these. Do you think that's what's causing the problem?

Comment: @dbmitch: All MSDN pages look like that. Click on "Other versions" and ta-da: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193499(v=office.14).aspx

Answer (score 2):

I'd say you are missing a line like

```vb
report.RecordSource = "the query that fills <recordset>"
```

But I'm pretty sure that there must be a better way to achieve your goal than creating a new report from scratch.

And it's error-prone to name your variables like their data types (`label`, `report`, ...)

---

**Edit**

Are you sure your SQL is valid? Alternatively, you can try saving it as query and pass the query name.

I did a little test, it should work principally. `r_tbProduct` has an empty recordsource when I run this:

```vb
Dim rep As Report

DoCmd.OpenReport "r_tbProduct", acViewDesign
Set rep = Reports!r_tbProduct
rep.RecordSource = "SELECT * FROM tbProduct WHERE ID >= 6"
DoCmd.OpenReport "r_tbProduct", acViewPreview
```

It shows the correct data.

Again, I strongly suggest you rename your variables.

```vb
Dim report As report
```

is just asking for problems.

Comment: I've added this in but now it is giving me the error message that Microsoft Access Database can't access the object on the line DoCmd.OpenReport. This error message is followed by the SQL string I'm using.

Comment: What exactly did you add? Please edit your question.

Comment: Edited. I added some new parameters to the function and the line you suggested to set the recordsource. After adding the recordsource line I started getting the error: The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object 'SELECT ... (the rest of the SQL String)'.

Comment: See edit. Not sure about the error if the SQL is valid.